# Using RestSharp to Map JSON to C# Classes

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

So I know there are probably other solutions to this. But my employer is intent on using the RestSharp package to Deserialize and execute a POST request using JSON Data. I know the data works because I've played with it on the API sandbox. I get a bad request error on debug. Here is the JSON Object in the sandbox:

```
{
    "stay": {
        "checkIn": "2016-06-08",
        "checkOut": "2016-06-10",
        "shiftDays": "2"
    },
    "occupancies": [
        {
            "rooms": 1,
            "adults": 2,
            "children": 1,
            "paxes": [
                {
                    "type": "AD",
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "type": "AD",
                    "age": 30
                },
                {
                    "type": "CH",
                    "age": 8
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "geolocation": {
    "longitude": 2.646633999999949,
    "latitude": 39.57119,
    "radius": 20,
    "unit": "km"
  }
}
```

and here is my representation in C#:

```
   var body = new TestRequest
        {

            stay = new Stay
            {
                checkIn = "2016-06-18",
                checkOut = "2016-06-10",
                shiftDays = 2
            },

            occupancies = new Occupancy[]
            {
                new Occupancy
                {
                    rooms = 1,
                    adults = 2, children = 1,
                    paxes = new Pax [] 
                    {
                        new Pax
                        {
                            type = "AD",
                            age = 30
                        },
                        new Pax
                        {
                            type = "AD",
                            age = 30
                        },
                        new Pax
                        {
                            type = "AD",
                            age = 30
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            geolocation = new Geolocation
            {
                longitude = 2.646633999999949F,
                latitude = 39.57119F,
                radius = 20,
                unit = "km"
            }

        };
```

What am I doing wrong here? I know there are probably easier ways to do this than RestSharp but I was told this was the method to use....so....help?

Here is the total code in the simple MVC app:

```
    string signature;

    using (var sha = SHA256.Create())
    {
        long ts = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalMilliseconds / 1000;
        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: " + ts);
        var computedHash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey + sharedSecret + ts));
        signature = BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "");
    }

    var client = new RestClient("https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest("/hotel-api/1.0/hotels", Method.POST);

    var body = new TestRequest
    {

        stay = new Stay
        {
            checkIn = "2016-06-18",
            checkOut = "2016-06-10",
            shiftDays = "2"
        },

        occupancies = new Occupancy[]
        {
            new Occupancy
            {
                rooms = 1,
                adults = 2, children = 1,
                paxes = new Pax [] 
                {
                    new Pax
                    {
                        type = "AD",
                        age = 30
                    },
                    new Pax
                    {
                        type = "AD",
                        age = 30
                    },
                    new Pax
                    {
                        type = "CH",
                        age = 8
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        geolocation = new Geolocation
        {
            longitude = 2.646633999999949F,
            latitude = 39.57119F,
            radius = 20,
            unit = "km"
        }

    };

    request.AddHeader("X-Signature", signature);
    request.AddHeader("Api-Key", apiKey);
    request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Complete guess-- `shiftDays` is a string in the test JSON that you said works in the API sandbox, but is an int in your non-working object.  Could it be a type conversion issue?  The rest of the request looks OK.  Only other difference I noticed is you have 2 AD and 1 CH Pax in the test JSON but 3 AD Pax in the object representation.

Comment: good ideas, im going to test...

Comment: no luck on the shiftDays...working on the second theory

Comment: dang no dice there either

Comment: can i post the rest for you to look at?

Comment: The more details you can provide, the better.  It might also help if you could mention what API this is, and where the specification is, if that is available.  Also, what is the code you are using when you post this request?

Comment: ok great, i pasted the rest of the code the error I'm getting is: "API does not work with specified version of the code" though this same request works in the sandbox. maybe its on their end? the api is APITUDE

Comment: If it works in one environment and not in the other, maybe you need different API keys (different credentials)? Can you log a support request with them, someone on their side may be able to answer it quickly for you.

Comment: good call im ready to go that route

Comment: As an aside:  "longitude = 2.646633999999949F"   These are better stored as decimals (6 decimal places) rather than floats so you don't get weird numbers like this.   Besides: trying to specify GPS coordinates down to the width of an atom probably isn't necessary ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pop your JSON in here: [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). I have used it successfully a number of times to validate. Bad request could be for a number of reasons - do you have a stacktrace or an error description either on the browser debug or in the code?

Have you got their [simple sample](https://developer.hotelbeds.com/docs/read/Home) on the web site up and running? It's a XML example but you can tweak it incrementally to get to where you need to be and help tick off items as working, like your api-key and shared secret being correct. Sometimes these are long strings and you accidentally chop a character or add a space with a cut and paste.

Also, consider dumping the RestSharp and get it working raw, then port it across to keep management happy :)

FYI - your JSON renders the following in json2csharp:

```
public class Stay
{
    public string checkIn { get; set; }
    public string checkOut { get; set; }
    public string shiftDays { get; set; }
}

public class Pax
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class Occupancy
{
    public int rooms { get; set; }
    public int adults { get; set; }
    public int children { get; set; }
    public List<Pax> paxes { get; set; }
}

public class Geolocation
{
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public int radius { get; set; }
    public string unit { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Stay stay { get; set; }
    public List<Occupancy> occupancies { get; set; }
    public Geolocation geolocation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: hi murray! yes i got the base call running, I can also call and get one hotel back...the post request especially in C# is proving a little trickier to get multiple back

Comment: and i changed the model to reflect what you put down...still same error

Comment: As per my comment on the prior post, see if you can find some support from the vendor. If it works in one environment and not in another then it is either: a) Credentials b) Invalid/wrong endpoint c) Something getting in your way (proxy, network, websense etc).  Tick those off your list then contact their support and maybe direct them to this thread, maybe they can respond here and save the next struggler some pain.

Comment: on the phone with them now, will do

Comment: Cool, let us know where the gremlin was.